# Visual Studio 2012 Schema Compare: Column Order and Constraint Names

Tags: sql, visual-studio, schema, compare

I'm experimenting with the SQL Schema Compare in Visual Studio 2012 Premium.

How do I ignore the column order in the comparison?

I found some posts that state this option was introduced in VS 2010, but I only see "Ignore column collation" the option in VS2012.
([Discussion for vs2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725269/why-does-schema-compare-in-visual-studio-2010-show-differences-when-there-are-no))

How do I ignore any differences in the names of the constraints in the comparison?

The constraints should be present, but do not need to have the same name.

Comment: Can you add some of the links that you refer to in the question to the question?

Answer (score 3):

The ignore column order was removed for VS2012 according to this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdt/thread/9613187c-3abb-4fbf-91c4-a927b26f45f1)

As for ignoring the constraint name the only way I could see it done is visually comparing it. I am assuming you are wanting to do this because you have system-generated constraint names. You can avoid system-generated constrain name to overcome the issue.